# How can I round perfectly a div with bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I was reading Bootstrap documentation and looking at stackoverflow for an answer and I found it. I have seen that border-radius can be used in a 50% value to make a circular image. I tried it that way, but it didn't work, because my image is a bit big. For some reason, it is always deformed. So I tried Bootstrap and the same thing happened to me.

Here I will put something of what I tried.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import yo from '../../assets/yo.jpg';
import './Card.css';

class Card extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row vertical-center">
                    <div className="">
                        <img src={yo} className="rounded-circle w-25" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Card
```

;
As you can see, it is a component in React. This is my css code:

```
.vertical-center {
    min-height: 80vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

What I am trying to do with this css is to align the content of the component vertically.

Then I get this result:

[image]

and it's not circular image :( how can I fix it with bootstrap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```css
.avatar-big {
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}

.avatar-small {
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
}

.avatar-med {
  height:75px;
  width:75px;
}


.avatar-img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-o-object-fit: cover;
object-fit: cover;
}

.rounded-circle {
border-radius: 50%!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar-big">
  <img class="avatar-img rounded-circle" src="https://i.insider.com/5c007f32499ade0d21195b72?width=1100&format=jpeg&auto=webp" />
</div>

<div class="avatar-med">
  <img class="avatar-img rounded-circle" src="https://i.insider.com/5c007f32499ade0d21195b72?width=1100&format=jpeg&auto=webp" />
</div>

<div class="avatar-small">
  <img class="avatar-img rounded-circle" src="https://i.insider.com/5c007f32499ade0d21195b72?width=1100&format=jpeg&auto=webp" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the min-heigh property, to get the well-rounded picture you need to have a width equal to the height

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your image isn't square, so your element won't be square either since there nothing in your CSS that forces it to be square.

Make it a fixed size, *both* width and height, so that it is square.

Then use `object-fit: cover` to ensure that the picture is positioned correctly inside it (it will always fill the box without getting deformed, "surplus" parts are just cut off).

Comment: I made it square, 300px wide and tall, but if I make it smaller, it deforms. How can I remedy that?

Comment: Make sure nothing else is messing with the size. Check in your devtools what effective CSS styles exist on the image element, if any of them are for example min-width/min-height/max-width/max-height/flex, or left/right/top/bottom